# Java, read x-,y-,z-coordinates from a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filereader

I am making 3D-Objects made of Triangles. These Triangles  have 3 Vectors.
Now I have a file with alot of numbers... If a line starts with "v" the line has x-, y-, and z-coordinates of a Vector.
If a line starts with "f" the line has the line of the Vector in the .txt file that I need for my Triangle.
The file starts with all "v"s first and then continues with the "f"s.

Example: (the number at the beginning is just the line)

21 v 1.2000 0.20000 -1.0000 -> Vector1(1.2, 0.2, -1)

22 v 1.2000 0.20000 1.00000 -> Vector2(1.2, 0.2, 1)

23 v -1.200 -0.2000 1.00000 -> Vector3(-1.2, -0.2, 1)

...

71 f 21 23 22 -> Triangle(Vector1, Vector3, Vector2)

And this is what i tried, which obviously did not work since I am a Java newbie :P

```
public static ArrayList<Triangle> mesh = new ArrayList<>();

public static void loadObject(String fileName) {
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileName);
        ArrayList<Vector> vectors = new ArrayList<>();

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            if (scan.equals("v")) {
                Vector v = new Vector();
                int i = 0;
                while (scan.hasNextDouble() && i < 3) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        v.setX(scan.nextDouble());
                    }
                    if (i == 1) {
                        v.setY(scan.nextDouble());
                    }
                    if (i == 2) {
                        v.setZ(scan.nextDouble());
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                vectors.add(v);
            }
            if (scan.equals("f")) {
                Triangle t = new Triangle();
                int j = 0;
                while (scan.hasNextInt() && j < 3) {
                    if (j == 0) {
                        t.setVec1(vectors.get(scan.nextInt() - 1));
                    }
                    if (j == 1) {
                        t.setVec2(vectors.get(scan.nextInt() - 1));
                    }
                    if (j == 2) {
                        t.setVec3(vectors.get(scan.nextInt() - 1));
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                mesh.add(t);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `scan.equals("v")` is always false. After calling `hasNextLine()`, you need to call `nextLine()` to get the line, *then* parse the line.

Comment: or just `next()` since you need the next token (word)... but I personally don't like the `Scanner` and prefer to use a `BufferedReader`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
static List<Triangle> parse(String fileName) 
{
  List<Triangle> mesh = new ArrayList<>();  
  Map<String, Vector> vm = new HashMap<>();

  try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName)))
  {
    while(scan.hasNextLine()) 
    {
      String[] p = scan.nextLine().split("\\s");
      if("v".equals(p[1]))
      {
        vm.put(p[0], new Vector(Double.parseDouble(p[2]), Double.parseDouble(p[3]), Double.parseDouble(p[4])));
      }
      else if("f".equals(p[1]))
      {
        mesh.add(new Triangle(vm.get(p[2]), vm.get(p[3]), vm.get(p[4])));
      }
    }
  }
  catch(IOException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return mesh;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are describing the [Wavefron OBJ file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) for which many loaders already exist. You should consider using an existing loader instead of rolling your own.

Googling for it I find three Java .obj loaders on Github right away:

- [javagl/Obj](https://github.com/javagl/Obj)
- [seanrowens/oObjLoader](https://github.com/seanrowens/oObjLoader)
- [Blunderchips/LWJGL-OBJ-Loader](https://github.com/Blunderchips/LWJGL-OBJ-Loader)

I have not used any of these so you would need to try them out yourself and see if they provide the right API for you and solve your concrete problem.

Comment: I'd also like to propose another alternative, our jvm Assimp [port](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/assimp) :)